Floor function of type $\left \lfloor\frac{c}{x}+b \right\rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{b}{x}+c \right\rfloor = d$
let us take a floor function of type $$\left \lfloor\frac{x}{m-1} \right\rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{m+a} \right\rfloor$$
eg. $\left \lfloor\frac{x}{99} \right\rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{101} \right\rfloor$ (where [.] denotes greatest integer function/floor function)
to solve this type of equation we can use properties of floor function.
let $[x/99]=[x/101]=k$
then $99k\le x\le99k+99$......(1)
similarly
$101k\le x\le101k+101$.....(2)
from (1) and (2) we can write $2k \le99$ or $k=0,1,2,3,4....49$
from this, we can solve for $x$ if it is an integer or positive integer solution..
MY DOUBT: how to proceed with a question in the format of
$$\left \lfloor\frac{c}{x}+b \right\rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{b}{x}+c \right\rfloor = d$$where $d$,$b$,$c$ are given (integers)and we have to find the possible value for $x$
What I tried: first I wrote the equation as
$$\left \lfloor\frac{c}{x} \right\rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{b}{x} \right\rfloor+c+b = d$$
now let us take $[d-(b+c) =w]$
then the whole equation will become
$$\left \lfloor\frac{c}{x} \right\rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{b}{x} \right\rfloor = w$$
how to proceed from this? Any ideas or hints would be appreciated. If I made any mistake also plz mention or request for edit

everything is integers,my bad z should not exist rt?... i have changed z to d
